# Suspend from console without leaving authenticated terminal on wake up

Tags: debian, suspend

I want to suspend my computer from terminal (one obtained by CTR+ALT+F1).

If I call:

```
# echo -n mem > /sys/power/state
```

after wakeup I'm leaving an authenticated console with (possibly) root credentials open to anyone.

Is there any elegant way to suspend the computer without leaving this console open?

Background: Suspend button is not working on my XFCE desktop and because of many reasons I don`t want to fix it right now. So it is easier to just suspend from terminal.

Comment: What do you think about screen locking mechanisms?

Comment: I'didn't want to go into that much detail in the question, in my case I mostly work in Gnome3, sometimes (on conferences) i disable nVidia card and work on xfce (to have better battery life). Everytime i do this suspend does not work beacause some incompatible change. So it's easier for me just to do it from console...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution (it is not very clean).

I created a script called `/sbin/suspend.sh` containing:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n mem > /sys/power/state
```

and then in my `.bashrc` file added following alias:

```
alias dosuspend='sudo suspend.sh && exit'
```

Now whenever I call `dosuspend` console is logged out right after wakeup.